# How is the "eye POV" shot made?

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography

The technique is extremely ubiquitous in movies and TV shows where an "eye POV" shot is used when a character closes their eyes when sleeping or when awake and we see the back of their eyelids or a character opens their eyes.

All people and animals in real life see the back of their eyelids when they close their eyes when awake or when sleeping. How is this technique made?

Answer (score 5):

This is covered under the term of POV in general, or point of view, and after the footage is filmed, a process of post production, often lasting longer than the filming production process itself, takes place.

In post you add, tweak, remove, change, edit, etc to form the footage you filmed into the movie you want others to see.

Lots of movies have short segments that might be from the protagonists eye pov, but there are some movies that try and make it all the way through from that perspective.

OP asks:

> how did they make this technique?

In short, the camera is placed roughly where we think our point of view would be, they record or film the scene and then in post production, they add the eye effects to the footage filmed to make it look as if it is from the eye.

Hardcore Henry, a 2015 science fiction action film is one that portrays this perspective.

Shown here is the pov in the film, and then how they filmed it (gopro strapped to the actors face)

[image]

same again:

[image]

Clearly there is no contraption added here to mimic eyes closing or blinking, so
things like closing eyes and blinking, etc are **added in postproduction**.

That way you have editorial control over when such things happen, and of course, a lot of that is artistic license.

In fact, as a film maker, you can just buy a preset and drop it in on your timeline:

> Blinking Eyes Premiere Pro presets presents a first-person imitation of closing eyes. Add this to your POV videos, or any personal or stylized videos.

etc etc

> how to imitate the point-of-view (POV) eye blinking effect

> Create the point of view eyes opening effect in Adobe After Effects

Comment: Many people and animals in real life see the back of their eyelids when they close their eyes when awake or when sleeping, but it isn't something to replicate in movies just like in real life, the eye POV shot is mostly done in postproduction in most films.

Comment: Are you a bot? ...

Comment: I bet someone at some time has done this as a practical, with a model pair of eyelids made of papier-maché, in something amusingly low budget. It wouldn't be too tough to set it far enough inside focus to look cheesily approximate. I'd love to see the stills of the camera setup ;)